# Taglist: Exuberant ctags not found in PATH

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

This morning, I started getting that message when I attempt to open a file in Vim. Vim is my editor of choice for config files, git commit messages and the like, but is not my day to day code editor. I clearly did something to invite this message, but I have no idea what. I did recently uninstall an older version of XCode from `/Developer-3.2.6`, but that's the only thing that comes to mind that seems even tangentially related.

I'm running OSX Lion. Is Excuberant ctags part of the base install? I know I didn't install it intentionally, but if it's not native, then maybe it came along with something else? Any ideas about how to either get the plugin back or remove references to it so I don't get the warning message?

Thanks.

Comment: On my machine, it's in /Developer/usr/bin/

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Are you running XCode 3.x or 4?

Comment: It's an old one.  3.x, I think.

Comment: just add /Developer/usr/bin to your path as Paul suggested and you should be good. No need to reinstall xcode

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That looks a lot like the message the [taglist](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=273) plugin emits when it can't find a ctags program.  If you run `:scriptnames`, do you see `plugin/taglist.vim` in the list of sourced files?  If you do, then you'll probably want to remove that and `doc/taglist.txt` under the same directory structure.

Comment: I do see that plugin in the list, I'm just not sure where it went, I guess. Reinstalling XCode seems to have fixed whatever the problem may have been.

Comment: @Rob, I told you what the problem was. :) The taglist plugin couldn't find a ctags program.  You reinstalled XCode, which provided a ctags program, so taglist stopped complaining.

Comment: Fair enough. Someone might as well get the points in spite of my rather unenlightened and ham-fisted solution. :-)

Comment: `rm ~/.vim/plugin/taglist.vim ~/.vim/doc/taglist.txt`

Answer (score 44):

For Ubuntu and derivatives:

```
sudo apt-get install exuberant-ctags
```

With yum:

```
sudo yum install ctags-etags
```

Comment: You should clarify that this is intended only for Ubuntu and its derivatives.

Comment: It worked for me, thank you.
The error msg reveals that  exuberant-ctags  program not installed, so, just install it and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 14):

FWIW I had the same error message on Ubuntu, I simply installed [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html) and everything hunky dory. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Gvim in a Windows system, you should download a ctag Windows program (that is ctag.exe) and put the ctag.exe in the vim74 file dir, then reboot Gvim, and it will find it and use it! I hope this is helpful.

Take a look at this: http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/installation.html

Comment: i put that ctags.exe every where except in my "C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74". Thanks for the tip. Now C:\Program Files (x86)\vim\vim74\ctags.exe let Tlist open and do the job ;)

Comment: So, you probably _shouldn't_ put this in your vim install folder, because if you uninstall vim, it won't get removed. Instead, put it somewhere else, then in Windows, update your user `PATH` environment variable to add the folder path to where `ctags.exe` is located. If you have an existing terminal session open, you will need to restart it. But then Vim will find the executable with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, guys. I ended up reinstalling XCode and it looks like the problem has gone away. I have no idea how I got it into whatever state it was in, but it's back now and everything looks to be back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after upgrading to Mountain Lion.  I fixed it by reinstalling the CLI tools from XCode preferences > Downloads.  I had the CLI tools installed before upgrading.  Not sure what happened, but it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue on a host, but I didn't have permission to install any packages.

But i did find out the `gctags` was present on that system.

I created a softlink for the gctags binary in a location that was included in my PATH environment variable.

```
$ln -s /usr/bin/gctags ~/bin/ctags**
```

You can do the same if you find `etags` binary in your system, and have no way to install any packages.